# What is the reason for migrating this question?

Tags: discussion, migration, migrated-questions

My question on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9693446/grouping-strings-by-common-themes?noredirect=1) was recently migrated to [Stats](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/25367/grouping-strings-by-common-themes). I was notified upon logging in, but nowhere did I find a reason behind it. I am curious as to the reason why the question was moved. I feel that the choice is not 100% beneficial to my question.

I was looking more so for a programming answer than a statistical/abstract answer.

**Update:** I feel that my question ([the previous one](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/25367/grouping-strings-by-common-themes)) wasn't crystal clear. Should I simply reword and ask a *new* question on SO? Advice for improving my question are gladly welcome?

Comment: Probably because (based on a quick glance) you're asking about theory and algorithms (a very broad "how") rather than code?  If you were looking for a programming answer you would have needed to pick an algorithm and been asking about a point of implementation (or something like that).

Comment: I say something along the lines of "using software/programming" in the first couple of lines. I don't know enough to single out an algo. and ask about it.

Comment: If you said "I want to do this manually by hand" (which would be crazy but that's besides the point) the question would look exactly the same.  You're not asking how to code something, you're asking how to do something that you happen to want to implement with code once you figure it out.  Until you get to the stage that actual involves code I don't think it's an SO type of question.

Comment: "Using software/a program, how can I solve world hunger?" - not everything that has the word 'software' or 'programming' in it is fit for SO.

Comment: @Mat: The simple answer to your question would be "it can't be done". The simple answer to my question would be "use tool X". I'm trying to find tool X, not solve world hunger.

Comment: That's not my point. Your argument "I say software in there" is really weak.

Comment: While the person who posted an answer to your question on stats didn't hand you any actual code, he did give a well-thought out, detailed answer about the algorithms that can be used.  I daresay the question got better handling on stats than it might have on SO, considering that you didn't show any code yourself.

Comment: @Mat: Then what was the point?

Comment: @RobertHarvey Just so you know, that answer was from when the question was on SO.

Comment: That your "I say something along the lines of "using software/programming" in the first couple of lines." is a very weak argument.

Comment: @Whymarrh: Ah, I see that. Well, there's a moderator flag on your question. It reads *"Off topic, not constructive, and bounty-protected. Jeopardy as a tag?"* The edit history on your question is a mess, and suggests that you don't know how to use the tag system properly. Clearly, there were problems with your question; looks to me like the moderator who migrated it was just trying to save it somehow.

Comment: I see your edit; I'd be more inclined to reopen your original question on SO if you can edit to clean it up.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I had reasons behind the specific tags, but my error was not making them clear. Maybe you could post some resources on the tag system to allow me to avoid the same mistakes in the future. I'd appreciate your reopening the question very much, but it'd be best to know the specific errors in my question. If you could post your ideas as an answer, I'd gladly accept that.

Comment: See [@casperOne's answer below](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/127172).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I migrated the question.

Your problem essentially boils down to a clustering and classification problem.

If you knew the categories beforehand, then it would be a classification issue (e.g. [naive Baysean classifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naive_Bayes_classifier), [k-nearest-neighbor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-nearest_neighbor_algorithm)).

In this case, you don't, so it's a clustering problem (e.g. [k-means clustering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering)).  You want to group like things together without actually knowing what those like things are.

Regardless, these topics are covered *extensively* on Cross Validated, as their [tags page currently indicates](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags) (both `clustering` and `classification` are currently on the first page of tags).

The fact that you want to do it "in software" doesn't make it more suitable for Stack Overflow.  Your first problem is that you aren't sure *what* to do, Cross Validated will help you figure that out.

When you figure out the what, then I'd recommend a *new* question on Stack Overflow if you have issues with the *how*.

Note, I don't dislike the question, [I rather like statistics questions](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/740/casperone?tab=questions); it was migrated because I knew that the community there is more focused on problems such as this (and yes, they use software/code to solve them) and believe that it's presence there would get you a better result, given that you have more of a problem with the approach than actual code.

---

P.S. I burninated the [jeopardy](/questions/tagged/jeopardy) tag before migrating that question; it had six questions it was applied to and has no real reason (currently) to exist on Stack Overflow.

[image: burninated]

Comment: Just for the record, I had tagged my question with Jeopardy because the questions were from Jeopardy!. Thank you for the response.